# VBA Excel Cannot find DLL

Tags: vba, excel, dll

I am currently trying to add control to a Power Analyzer in an excel tool.  The company provides USB drivers and the appropriate modules and DLLs.  I added the DLLs to the System32 folder to ensure they were read in the path.  After importing the modules and trying to run the program, I get the error "File Not Found".  I then tried to hard code the location of the DLL and I received the same error.

I've looked around the internet and the only issue I could find was possibly a dependency missing from the DLL.  An example of the line I'm trying to use is:

```
Declare Function TmSend Lib "tmctl.dll" (ByVal id As Long, ByVal msg As String) As Long
```

This line is apart of the module provided by the manufacturer.  Is there something I'm missing to get this to work?  I want to make sure before I contact the manufacturer.

**EDIT:**

It appears that the manufacturer uploaded a corrupt DLL causing the issue to arise.  When checking the file with Dependency Walker, it failed to even read the DLL.

Comment: In Excel got to Tools -> References and add a reference to the DLL (In the VBA IDE)

Comment: `I added the DLLs to the System32 folder to ensure they were read in the path.` Is it registered using `Regsvr32`

Comment: @SiddharthRout When I run that command, I get an error that says `The module was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.`

Comment: @Fred DLL isn't required at all to be in references. References is for COM, `Declare` is for accessing external procedures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see from your question that you've tried all the normal things (making sure the dll is on your path &c.)

You now need to examine the dll carefully. Download this: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Then use it to open your dll. All the missing dependent dlls will be clearly displayed. Put those on your path too and you're done.

(To clear up some confusion: you will not need to register this dll or add a reference to it.)

Comment: + 1 Ah! Dependency Walker! How could I have missed that :) Nicely done