# Why my vba works when created from scratch, but when I save and open the file I get run-time error 53?

Tags: excel, vba, dll

I have the following code. If I create an .xlsm file **from scratch** and execute the code, it works perfectly. However, if I save that file, open it again and run the code, it shows an run-time error '53' file not found.

How can I fix it? What am I doing wrong? DLL is correctly placed in the path. Otherwise it shouldn't work when I create the file from scratch.

The code:

```
Declare Function StartJob Lib "C:\Users\d645daar\Downloads\DLL DBM\calcdll.dll" (ByRef p1 As Double, ByRef p2 As Variant, ByRef p3 As Double) As Boolean
Declare Function SetPricePath Lib "C:\Users\d645daar\Downloads\DLL DBM\calcdll.dll" (ByRef p1 As String)

Const NINPUTDATA = 100
Const NRESDATA = 100
Const NOPTIONSDATA = 1
Const P60 = 1

Sub StartCalc_Clicked()

Dim bErr As Boolean
Dim aInputData(NINPUTDATA) As Double
Dim aResult(NRESDATA) As Variant
Dim aOptions(NOPTIONSDATA) As Variant

'On Error GoTo StartCalc_exit

'Collect data from input mask
aInputData(0) = 1 'coil type P60
aInputData(1) = 32 'inlet temperature 32°C
aInputData(2) = 50 '50% R.H.
aInputData(5) = 2000 'air volume 2000 Sm3/h
aInputData(14) = 4 '4 Rows
aInputData(15) = 10 '10 tubes per row
aInputData(16) = 2 'fin pitch 2.0 mm
aInputData(17) = 4 '4 circuits
aInputData(18) = 500 'coil length 500 mm
aInputData(26) = 7 'water inlet temp 7 °C
aInputData(27) = 12 'water outlet temp 12 °C
'aInputData(52) = 2 'PRICE MULTIPLIER

'Prices
'SetPricePath (".\\")

a = StartJob(aInputData(0), aResult(0), aOptions(0))

'MsgBox ("Warning code: " & aResult(71))
MsgBox ("Selected coil: " & aResult(29) & " Price: " & aResult(28)) 'Simple result processing
End Sub
```

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19590732/2806502). I have had similar errors like this and it was some other dependency dll that the dll could not find. Though it is weird that it works for you before you save. Maybe the working directory is different somehow and it cannot find the dll?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment.
That was it. Working directory was not correct somehow. I checked it and apparently when I open a new .xlsm file, working directory is where that file is placed, but when I save it, close it and reopen it again, working directory is in "My Documents". Weird to be honest, but at least now I know the error.
Thanks!!